# Springboot JPA Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jparepository

I am creating a JPA Repository in Springboot.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;


public class UserRepository extends JPARepository<User, Long>{
    
}
```

The error that I am getting is that I cannot resolve the JPA Repository library.

In Maven, on pom.xml, I put

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I did maven clean, validate, and install. In the pom.xml file, I am not getting any errors. However, on my repository code, I am getting JPARepository not found despite the fact I imported "import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository."

Comment: [`JpaRepository` (`docs.spring.io`)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) is an interface, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Use **interface** instead of **class**, like below

```java
public interface UserRepository extends JPARepository<User, Long>{
    
}
```